# How to keep the size of table column be same irrespective of android view

Tags: android

i am adding a table row on button click event. my row has got 2 textview and 2 spinners and 1 EditText. I want the size of the columns to be same, however spinner's size changes as per the selected value. Please help on this and share some lights.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <TableLayout

        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableRow

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp">

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".2"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="S.No"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".2"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Product"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:layout_weight=".2"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Product List"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>


        <TextView

            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Price"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>
        <TextView

            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Quantity"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>
        </TableRow>
        <!--<TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tr1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"/>-->
    </TableLayout>

    <TableLayout
android:id="@+id/tlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Add Item"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"><Button
        android:id="@+id/confirm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"

        /></LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add the Layout's XML?, it would be easier to help you.

Comment: I have added the xml layout

Comment: are you adding the new row programmatically? if that is the case are you using a layout and a LayoutInflater?

Comment: yes,i am getting the TableLayout (id:tLayout) and adding the row to its view

Answer (score 0):

If the spinner is growing to match the selected value you most probably have `layout_width` set to `wrap_content`

It sounds like you should be using something more like [layout_weight](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight) to correctly use up the horizontal space

Edit:
I don't see where this view will scroll if it grows too large. It sounds like you should be using a [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) or [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) instead of your TableLayout.
Each item in the list could be something like:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listItemPreferredHeight"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/some_text"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/some_more_text"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
</LinearLayout>
```

Note: layout written off the top of my head, may not be perfectly valid :P

You could obviously put controls and weights that match what you want, but from your question I'm assuming this is the expected behavior you seek

Comment: With wrap_content the spinners grows to the size of selected item, with layout_weight i am not getting the expected behaviour

Comment: I've edited my answer to address the new information, hopefully it helps

Comment: Thanks Keith for above suggestion, i will try the listview and update